# Write in the next column of CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, csvwriter

I have a simple code that should write values in two columns, I would like to have the results shown as:
0.48     2.71
But I can only write in rows, how do I write the rows in the second column (I want to have the fines percentages in one column and 'X' in the second column)? your help is much appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
import csv
finespacking = 0.55
d63fine= 2
coarsepacking= 0.6
d63coarse = 5
x=[]
percentage_fines_agg= [0.48,0.49,0.50,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.60] 
rows = [[data] for data in x]
for item in percentage_fines_agg:
    with open ('tempmix.csv') as temp_mix_file:
        x= (item/(1-item))* (coarsepacking/finespacking)/(1-coarsepacking)
        writer= csv.writer(temp_mix_file)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the current output and the desired / expected output?

Comment: Hi, I want to have all of the items in the first column and all of the x in the second column, like this:
0.48 (in the first column)         2.517 (in the second column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this without Pandas you could do something like:

```py
import csv


finespacking = 0.55
coarsepacking = 0.6
factor = (coarsepacking / finespacking) / (1 - coarsepacking)
with open("tempmix.csv", "w", newline="") as out_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for x in range(48, 60 + 1):
        x /= 100
        y = factor * x / (1 - x)
        csv_writer.writerow([x, y])
```

compared to your snippet, the key modifications are:

- open the file outside of the loop
- instantiate the `csv.writer()` outside of the loop
- use `csv_writer.writerow()` to write each row at once
- the row includes both the value from `percentage_fines_agg` and the value computed form it

I also took the liberty of introducing the following non-mandatory but helpful modification:

- removing unused variables
- simplifying the calculations (defining a `factor` outside of the loop)
- simplifying some variable names
- generating the `percentage_fines_agg` values dynamically.

---

If you want to use Pandas, this is much simpler to write:

```py
import pandas as pd


finespacking = 0.55
coarsepacking = 0.6
factor = (coarsepacking / finespacking) / (1 - coarsepacking)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(48, 60 + 1))
df[0] /= 100
df[1] = factor * df[0] / (1 - df[0])
df.to_csv("tempmix.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

---

In both cases, the content of `tempmix.csv` is the following:

```
0.48,2.517482517482517
0.49,2.620320855614973
0.5,2.727272727272727
0.51,2.8385899814471243
0.52,2.9545454545454546
0.53,3.0754352030947776
0.54,3.2015810276679844
0.55,3.3333333333333335
0.56,3.4710743801652897
0.57,3.6152219873150093
0.58,3.7662337662337655
0.59,3.9246119733924605
0.6,4.09090909090909
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked!
what does the "/" in df[0] / mean?
thanks again, I've been trying to figure this out for several hours.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) The `x /= y` is equivalent to `x = x / y`. This is the [*in-place* operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators) associated to [division](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itruediv).

Comment: Awesome, I learned many new stuff today, thanks to you and the other person's comments. wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

- in the CMD : install pandas `pip install pandas`

and then in the script

```
      import pandas as pd
      df = pd.read_csv('tempmix.csv')
      for item in percentage_fines_agg:
          df["second_column_name"] = the_value_you_need_to_store

      # And if u want to save the new created file :
      df.to_csv("new_file_name.csv")
```

You will fine the new file called new_file_name.csv in the working directory

Comment: @yahya just edited the response

Comment: Should the df.to_sav be outside of the for command?
here is the new code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('tempmix2.csv')
percentage_fines_agg= [0.48,0.49,0.50,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.60]
for item in percentage_fines_agg:
    df["fines"] = item
    df["test"] = item + 1
df.to_csv("newfile.csv")

the answer I get is:
,fines,test

Answer (score 0):

just use comma "," to go the next cell "value1,value2"
use the "\n" to go to the next row "value1\nvalue2"
good luck